# Check instanceof in stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, instanceof

I have the following expression:

```java
    scheduleIntervalContainers.stream()
            .filter(sic -> ((ScheduleIntervalContainer) sic).getStartTime() != ((ScheduleIntervalContainer)sic).getEndTime())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

...where `scheduleIntervalContainers` has element type `ScheduleContainer`:

```
final List<ScheduleContainer> scheduleIntervalContainers
```

Is it possible to check the type before the filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly a stream, but Guava's `FluentIterable` does this very cleanly:

```
FluentIterable.from(scheduleIntervalContainers)
        .filter(ScheduleIntervalContainer.class)
        .filter(sic -> sic.getStartTime() != sic.getEndTime())
        .toList();
```

Answer (score 204):

You can apply another `filter` in order to keep only the `ScheduleIntervalContainer` instances, and adding a `map` will save you the later casts:

```java
    scheduleIntervalContainers.stream()
        .filter(sc -> sc instanceof ScheduleIntervalContainer)
        .map(sc -> (ScheduleIntervalContainer) sc)
        .filter(sic -> sic.getStartTime() != sic.getEndTime())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or, as Holger commented, you can replace the lambda expressions with method references if you prefer that style:

```java
    scheduleIntervalContainers.stream()
        .filter(ScheduleIntervalContainer.class::isInstance)
        .map(ScheduleIntervalContainer.class::cast)
        .filter(sic -> sic.getStartTime() != sic.getEndTime())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Or `.filter(ScheduleIntervalContainer.class::isInstance) .map(ScheduleIntervalContainer.class::cast)`, whatever style you prefer.

Comment: In IDEA and Java8, if the above snippet is assigned to  List<ScheduleContainer> scheduleIntervalContainers, it still prompts me to cast the result to  List<ScheduleContainer> scheduleIntervalContainers explicitly, do you know why?

Comment: @K.Symbol Did you try to assign to a `List<ScheduleContainer>` or a `List<ScheduleIntervalContainer>`? It should be the latter.

Answer (score 140):

A pretty elegant option is to use method reference of class:

```
scheduleIntervalContainers
  .stream()
  .filter( ScheduleIntervalContainer.class::isInstance )
  .map( ScheduleIntervalContainer.class::cast )
  .filter( sic -> sic.getStartTime() != sic.getEndTime())
  .collect(Collectors.toList() );
```

Comment: What benefit is there to this style compared to using instanceof and (ScheduleIntervalContainer) to cast?

Comment: @MageWind that’s mostly a matter of style. Some people prefer it, because you don’t have to introduce another variable name (for the lambda parameter), others, because it generates slightly less byte code (not enough difference to be really relevant though).

Comment: This is really cool! But why is the `.class` required? isn't `isInstance` part of `Object`? Is `Class` a class in Java?

Comment: @PostSelf Indeed, it is and `ScheduleIntervalContainer` wouldn't really be a an instance.

Comment: Using method references instead of lambdas is usually more readable ;)

Answer (score 16):

There is a small problem with @[Eran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1221571/eran) solution - typing class name in both `filter` and `map` is error-prone - it is easy to forget to change the name of the class in both places. An improved solution would be something like this:

```
private static <T, R> Function<T, Stream<R>> select(Class<R> clazz) {
    return e -> clazz.isInstance(e) ? Stream.of(clazz.cast(e)) : null;
}

scheduleIntervalContainers
  .stream()
  .flatMap(select(ScheduleIntervalContainer.class))
  .filter( sic -> sic.getStartTime() != sic.getEndTime())
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However there might be a performance penalty in creating a `Stream` for every matching element. Be careful to use it on huge data sets. I've learned this solution from @[Tagir Vailev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4856258/tagir-valeev)

Comment: In this approach you must take care of NullPointerExceptions, since `select(A.class)` will return `null` for anything that is not an `A`. Adding `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` would help. BTW: @Eran's approach is null-safe.

Comment: Sorry, my bad... JavaDoc of  `flatMap` says "If a mapped stream is null an empty stream is used, instead.". So your solution was correct, even without the null-filter.

Comment: Still (IMO) odd to return `null` when you could've just returned an empty stream

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a filter + map like other answers suggest, I would recommend this utility method:

```
public static <Super, Sub extends Super> Function<Super, Stream<Sub>> filterType(Class<Sub> clz) {
  return obj -> clz.isInstance(obj) ? Stream.of(clz.cast(obj)) : Stream.empty();
}
```

Use it as:

```
Stream.of(dog, cat fish)
  .flatMap(filterType(Dog.class));
```

Compared to filter + map it has the following advantages:

- If the class does not extend your class you will get a compile error
- Single place, you can never forget to change a class in either filter or map

Answer (score 2):

Filter by class type with [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex)

```
StreamEx.of(myCollection).select(TheThing.class).toList();
```