# How do I get all instances of a subclass in a List of its superclass?

Tags: java

`Bar` is a class that extends `Foo`.

```
public class Foo {
    // Class content
}

public class Bar extends Foo {
    private int specialID;  // Set in the constructor, *not* a unique value
    // Class content
}
```

In my Main class, I have a `List<Foo>` that contains instances of both `Foo` and `Bar`. I want a method that returns a list of all the Bar that meet a condition. Here's what I've tried

```
public class Main {

private List<Foo> fooList = ...;  // The list is populated at initialisation time

public List<Bar> getBarsWithID(int id) {
    return fooList
        .stream()
        .filter(f -> f instanceof Bar)
        .filter(b -> b.getSpecialId() == id)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

}
```

However I am getting a lovely error saying that I cannot use `b.getSpecialId()` because my `Foo` class does not have it, and `fooList` contains instances of `Foo`.
Is there any way to let the compiler know that I've filtered that out? Or am I making a mistake in thinking that I have - does `f instanceof Bar` not guarantee that?

Comment: Perhaps this will help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35740543

Comment: That's perfect, cheers